# How to send data to controller through AJAX+HTTPPost

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a webpage where in i have a form which contains 2 text boxes & a dynamically generated table using jquery. The dynamic table contains only one column 'Name'. I want to send all the data to my controller??

Comment: Show us your View and Controller Code. That will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `POST` (i.e. `$.post`) to send your data serialized in a JS object to the controller:

```
$.post({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MyController/MyAction",
  data: serializedData,
  success: successFunction
});
```

Recover the data in your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  [HttpPost]
  public string MyAction(List<string> serializedData) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Textbox/Hidden insde the column and get data on these textbox/hiddens. All should be same name eg. `name="dummy"`.
Now on submit to controller get them as

```
Request.Form("dummy");
```

Please clarify your requirement if this is not so.